# Making a number base converter in JFRAME

Tags: java, swing, jframe, converters

So I have a JFrame file which contains 3 text boxes, a "Convert!" and a "Clear" button. The 3 text boxes are to input numbers from Hexadecimal -- Decimal -- Binary. You can input in any field pertaining to that specific number base and it'll convert that number base into the other 2 number bases.

My question is this : How can I detect which number base I'm supposed to convert from? For example if someone does a conversion, and wants to convert again, and he inputs another value for any number base so that 2 of the values are equivalent in the number bases, and one isn't, the program would mess up as it wouldn't know which one to convert. How can I combat this problem. And if someone is doing their first conversion, how would I be able to detect if there is text in the textbook. Sorry I'm new to jframes and I barely know the syntax.

Comment: _Sorry I'm new to jframes and I barely know the syntax_ From what i understood, your problem isn't with `JFrame`s, it's with base-detection.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you could say that. I'm really having more logic issues, and I haven't even started

Comment: Ok, so the problem is related to base detection, it has nothing to do with `JFrame` and GUI programming, i would suggest to remove that part and talk about the problem you have. Your question starts with "i don't know how to detect the base" and ends with "how can i make a GUI?". To me this makes your question a bit unclear :)

Comment: Are you completely sure I should do that? The problem itself is kinda related to JFrames. The problem isn't base detection itself. There are 3 textboxes that are labeled "Binary" "Decimal" & "Hexadecimal" so detecting the bases isn't really a problem. The problem is I don't really know how to get the conversion values, despite the fact that I know how to do the conversion itself. I'm having this problem because there are 3 text fields and I don't know how I can "detect" in which textbox the user has made an input. If I were to do try/catch, there would be so much more code... Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, ok, i misunderstood the question. I'm making an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a Listener on each of the text fields and change the other text fields according to which one was changed by the user.

I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure which listener you have to add to receive an event AFTER the text field gets changed (InputMethodListener didn't seem to fire anything and KeyListener fires before the text changes) so in this example I'll use ActionListener, which means the user will have to press "enter" after typing in the number.

```
final JTextField hex = new JTextField("hex");
final JTextField dec = new JTextField("dec");
ActionListener act = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == hex) {
            dec.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(hex.getText(), 16)));
        } else if(e.getSource() == dec) {
            hex.setText(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(dec.getText())));
        }
    }
};
hex.addActionListener(act);
dec.addActionListener(act);
```

EDIT: This means you won't need the "Convert!" button though, if you **really** want that then you'll need to keep track of which text field was edited the last time.
Which you could do by doing:

```
JTextField lastEdited;
private void init() {
    //other init stuff
    final JTextField hex = new JTextField("hex");
    final JTextField dec = new JTextField("dec");
    KeyListener keyListener = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            lastEdited = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        }
    };
    hex.addKeyListener(keyListener);
    dec.addKeyListener(keyListener);
    JButton convert = new JButton("Convert!");
    convert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(lastEdited == hex) {
                dec.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(hex.getText(), 16)));
            } else if(lastEdited == dec) {
                hex.setText(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(dec.getText())));
            }
        }
    });
    //other init stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes. You'll probably want to catch NumberFormatExceptions though.

Comment: Hahahahahaha, Oh man, thanks a lot! I'm not really supposed to use toHexString or the other auto converts to the number bases, but I get the idea. I'm supposed to use listeners on each textfield and 

if(inputIsMade in decimalTextfield){
  Decimal2Hex();
  Decimal2Binary();
}

Comment: @Alowaniak I'm asking if you tested that because it doesn't work

Comment: @BackSlash Well I really did test **exactly** that code, so I don't see what doesn't work about it.

Comment: @Alowaniak Now you edited your code. If you try adding the `ActionListener` to the text field as you wrote the first time, when the user types some text it doesn't react, my comments were related to that code, now it works

Comment: @BackSlash I didn't edit the original code, I added a possible solution for in the case he really needs to convert when the button is pressed. And it does indeed not react to normal key strokes, in the text I've written that the user will have to press "enter" after typing in the number to make the `ActionListener` get an event.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `DocumentFilter` to each `JTextField` to perform the conversion:

```
DocumentFilter hexFilter = new DocumentFilter(){

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        String hexInput = hexTextField.getText();
        //process hex input
    }
};
((AbstractDocument) hexTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(hexFilter);
```

The `replace` method will be invoked everytime the user inserts a text in the text field.

You just have to take the input from the text field and process it.

> I'm having this problem because there are 3 text fields and I don't know how I can "detect" in which textbox the user has made an input.

You can add a different `DocumentFilter` to each text field, so you will always know *which* text field the user is writing to.

Something like:

```
((AbstractDocument) hexTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(hexFilter);
((AbstractDocument) octTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(octFilter);
((AbstractDocument) binTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(binFilter);
```

This way you will always know that `binFilter` handles binary input, `octFilter` handles octal input and `hexFilter` handles hexadecimal input.

---

Another option would be to use a `KeyListener`, but AFAIK it doesn't react when you paste some text in the text field.

Comment: I see. Thanks man, the help is really appreciated, but I'm going with listeners, Check my comment out on his comment and tell me if i'm doing it the right way.

Comment: Well I'm not going to copy paste the code exactly, I just plan to use listeners now. I'm going to figure out how though, I've never used them before, I JUST Learned about them like 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Wait, how come? I plan to do something like this. Code 6 methods prehand:
BinaryToHex(); And other 5 similar to those, and 3 if statements, If(action is made in decimalbox){ then call methods DecimalToHex(): & DecimalToBinary(); } Why wouldn't that work?